# CodeWars Challenge Error: Replacing with Alphabet Position

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this challenge, but my code doesn't seem to work, is there a fix? Here is the question:

In this kata you are required to, given a string, replace every letter with its position in the alphabet.

If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it.

"a" = 1, "b" = 2, etc.

Example
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
Should return "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11" ( as a string )

Here is my code:

`

```
def alphabet_position(text):
    new= ''
    a1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    a2 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    n= ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26']
    for i in range(0, len(text)-1):
        if i in a1:
            index= a1.index(i)
            new+= n[index]
        elif i in a2:
            index=a2.index(i)
            new+= n[index]            
    return new
```

`

Comment: What does “my code doesn’t work” mean? Incorrect result? Error message? Please be more explicit about this. Also, add an example of the input you use.

Comment: Instead of computing the index in 2 different lists, why not just `ord(letter.upper())` followed by a bit of arithmetic? Also -- shouldn't your code be inserting spaces between the numbers?

Comment: `for i in range(0, len(text)-1)` here i is a number (and not a character) which is not in either a1 or a2. So neither `if` and `elif` body is executed

Comment: 'If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it.' - as mentioned in the question above

Answer (score 3):

As previous posts (@John Coleman) suggested, it's easier to just use *ord* to solve it:

Credit to him and earlier comments.

```py
def alphabet_position(s):
  return " ".join(str(ord(c)-ord("a")+1) for c in s.lower() if c.isalpha())

# Or you still like your original mapping approach:

def alphabet_position(text):
    letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    
    return " ".join([str(letters.find(c) + 1)
                     for c in text.lower() if c in letters])


print(alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."))

# 20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. You are comparing the numerical index of a letter with `a1` and `a2`. No numerical index is a letter, so neither of your `if` branches are ever executed, which is why you always get the empty string returned. The solution is to directly iterate over the letters in `text`.
2. You aren't putting spaces between the numbers. The solution is to gather the numbers into a list and to then join them with a space delimiter.

Making these changes leads to the following code:

```
def alphabet_position(text):
    new= []
    a1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
    a2 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
    n= ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26']
    for i in text:
        if i in a1:
            index= a1.index(i)
            new.append(n[index])
        elif i in a2:
            index=a2.index(i)
            new.append(n[index])            
    return ' '.join(new)
```

For example

```
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
'20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11'
```

This answer shows how to debug your code so that it works. The answer by Daniel Hao shows a much more pythonic approach to the problem.